# SQLite - Index for rectangle intersection without GIS extension

Tags: sqlite, indexing, intersection

I have a quite large SQLite database to store some geo-data. I can't use the GIS extension and i'd also like everything to work with other databases as well.

My table structure is the following:

```
tbl(float fromLon, float fromLat, float toLon, float toLat, binary binaryData)
```

i store some binary-data within the database (the polygon of something) and store it's bounding-box in the form of fromLon,fromLat -> toLon,toLat.

Next i have some queries like "give me all binaryData (polygons) that are within this region (reqLlon1,reqLat1)-(reqLon2,reqLat2)".
a sample query would be:

```
SELECT binaryData
FROM tbl WHERE
(reqLon1 < toLon) AND
(reqLat1 < toLat) AND
(reqLon2 > fromLon) AND
(reqLat2 > fromLat)
```

The problem is, it seems that i can't figure the right index to speed things up.. a simple index like

```
idx1(fromLon,fromLat,toLon,toLat)
```

does not work out. I tried the same thing with MySQL (same layout, same index) and it states (explain select ..) that it only uses half of the index's length..

can someone give me a hint what the index should look like to work out? or could it be, that it's impossible?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the [R*Tree module](http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html).

> An R-Tree is a special index that is designed for doing range queries.
>   R-Trees are most commonly used in geospatial systems where each entry
>   is a rectangle with minimum and maximum X and Y coordinates. Given a
>   query rectangle, an R-Tree is able to quickly find all entries that
>   are contained within the query rectangle or which overlap the query
>   rectangle. This idea is easily extended to three dimensions for use in
>   CAD systems. R-Trees also find use in time-domain range look-ups.

Comment: I feared something like this.. Unfortunately I'm using SQLite within Java via JDBC. So there is no simple way of adding modules like GIS or R*Tree. Is there no other possibility? If not i think i have to switch to C/C++ anyway..

Comment: Can't you compile the JDBC driver from http://www.ch-werner.de/javasqlite/ yourself using the `--with-sqlite3=DIR` option (in addition to the `-DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE=1` option)?